# Oracle: Programmatic way to identify foreign key dependencies?

Tags: oracle

I would like to identify foreign key relationships among several tables.  Given a table name and column name, how can I identify what other tables have a foreign key relationship to that column?

```
(table name, column name) -> (list of tables,columns with FK dependency)
```

Comment: [ALL_CONSTRAINTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1046.htm#i1576022) [ALL_CONS_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1044.htm#i1575870)

Comment: There are ways to query the data dictionary to find defined FK constraints, as others will suggest. However, it should be noted that some applications may not have defined FK constraints and instead rely on the application to enforce database integrity. For example Oracle's own E-Business Suite does not use FK constraints in the database among the thousands of tables.

Comment: @JohnDoyle, I don't think this is a duplicate question.  This question wants a narrower scope of keys based on table and column.  The referenced question shows how to get all FK relationships in a schema.  Similar, but not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this possibly:

```
select x.owner || '.' || x.table_name || '.' || x.column_name childcol,
       y.owner || '.' || y.table_name || '.' || y.column_name parentcol,
       z.constraint_name
  from all_cons_columns x,
       all_cons_columns y,
       all_constraints z
 where x.constraint_name = z.constraint_name
   and z.owner = x.owner
   and y.constraint_name = z.r_constraint_name
   and z.constraint_type = 'R'
```

You would also need to include in your predicate whether the table you are looking for is the parent or the child in the foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I use this query to compare columns referenced by foreign keys, because our DBAs require them to be same type and same precision. Maybe it can help you.

You can use prefixes DBA, ALL or USER depending on your privileges:

```
SELECT   uc.constraint_name,ucc1.TABLE_NAME,ucc1.column_name,a.data_type||'('||nvl(a.data_precision,a.data_length)||')' length,
         ucc2.TABLE_NAME references_table,ucc2.column_name references_column, b.data_type||'('||nvl(b.data_precision,b.data_length)||')' length
FROM     user_constraints uc
,        user_cons_columns ucc1
,        user_cons_columns ucc2
,        user_tab_columns a
,        user_tab_columns b
WHERE    uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
and      a.column_name=ucc1.column_name
and      b.column_name=ucc1.column_name
and      uc.table_name=a.table_name
and      uc.table_name=b.table_name
AND      uc.r_constraint_name = ucc2.constraint_name
AND      ucc1.POSITION = ucc2.POSITION 
AND      uc.constraint_type = 'R'
ORDER BY ucc1.TABLE_NAME
,        uc.constraint_name;
```